# Standardizing pygame draw times

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, pygame

I am using pygame to perform a cognitive science experiment.

I am drawing objects to the screen -- the number of which can vary greatly: 4 - 24.
I draw them all at once when everything has been computed.
The problem is that, obviously, 24 items take much longer to compute than 4.
This results in variation in time between when the command is issued to start computing objects to draw and them actually being displayed on the screen.
It is only a few milliseconds, but that is experimental noise I'd like to avoid.

All objects *must* be displayed at the same time.

Below is the function I've written to do this.
All arguments are passed by the program pulling out information from a pandas data frame computed before the experiment begins. 
Perhaps computing how to draw items from that DF ahead of time would help, if at all possible.

```
def dot_draw(x_positions, y_positions, RGBs):
    for dot in range(0, len(x_positions)):
        pygame.draw.circle( screen, RGBs[dot], [ x_positions[dot], y_positions[dot] ], 10) 
    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> All objects must be displayed at the same time.

When you draw something on the screen surface, it is not displayed until you call `pygame.display.udpate()` or `pygame.display.flip()`.
So when you want that multiple changes are displayed at the same time, just call `pygame.display.update()` *once after* you're done with drawing all your circles etc on the screen surface.

---

*In response to your comment:*

If you know what to draw in advance, you could create several surfaces of the size of the screen, then draw to that surfaces instead of directly to the screen surface and later blit these to the screen surface.

Comment: Thanks -- but I am aware of that. My function, I hope, reflects that understanding. `pygame.display.update()` is only called when the `for` loop is complete. 
The problem is that the for loop can be passed anywhere from 4 - 24 items to draw, thus the time for it to complete its work can vary. My preference would be to perform all such computations ahead of time, not on the fly as the experiment proceeds.

Comment: If you know what to draw in advance, you could create several surfaces of the size of the screen, then draw to that surfaces instead of directly to the screen surface and later blit these to the screen surface.

Comment: My currently solution to this problem was to create images in memory with matplotlib and simply display them with pygame...It didn't occur to me that I need not leave pygame to accomplish this task (i.e., use multiple surfaces). 
So, that ought to work. Thank you!